# How to pass width to div from ts?

Tags: angular

I have this:

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.skillImgs.forEach((skill: ElementRef) => {
            console.log(skill.nativeElement,'native element');
       });

    }
```

My html:

```
<div #skillImg [style.width]="event.width" class="{{fixed ? 'fixed-div' : ''}}" *ngFor="let event of events">
    <header class="sticky"><span>{{event.datetime}}</span><span>{{event.date}}</span></header>
    <time-flow class="time-flow-child  z-table-view" *ngIf="event.event && !event.itemKey" [events]="event.event" [positions]="positions" [selected]="selected"></time-flow>
    <event-flow  class="z-col-24 nopadding z-event-cell" *ngIf="event.items" [events]="event.items" [positions]="positions" [selected]="selected"></event-flow>
</div>
```

What i want is to pass this width from skill.nativeElement.offsetWidth to div but i dont know how. Any suggestion? So right now i have two divs that returns native element and i want to pass them to html in style for both of them.

Comment: Are you just trying to style? [ngStyle]="{'width': event.width}" should do the trick

Comment: but i dont know how to pass value from ts to html. Because in ts im getting widthoffset

Comment: using brackets along with the quotes as I wrote it makes it dynamic, `event.width` is loaded from the ts

Comment: i know that but i mean how to set it in ts...i get this skill.nativeElement.offsetWidth where i get width for all divs, but problem is that i dont know to pass them in html for every of them. If u know what i mean?

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding what you want to accomplish...

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me:

```
<div [style.width]="event.width" *ngFor="let event of events">{{event.width}}</div>

events:any[]=[
        {width:'100px'},
        {width:'200px'}]
```